# php/js refresh variable without refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have problem with my php/js code.

I need to check every 1 second content of file, so before i'm going to load page i set adress.txt content to "localhost" then i go to my website and it displays me localhost, now i want to edit content of text file to "192.168.0.1", so i want to set automatically div text to new content without refresh, its still localhost not 192.168.0.1

My actual js:

```
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                $('#show').text("<?php echo file_get_contents("adress.txt");?>");
            }, 1000);
        });
```

How can i update div text to new txtfile content without refresh?

Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: You can't mix JS and PHP like that. You will need to send a ajax request from JS to a server side script that outputs the address (PHP). Then you can add the response from that request to the page.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. Your `<?php echo file_get_contents("adress.txt");?>` executes only when the page is loaded (or refreshed). Then, if you want to do anything without refreshing, you need to use javascript. If you want to call some PHP code without refreshing, you can use AJAX. And you even don't need PHP if you just want to get content of some file.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $.get('address.txt', function(data)
        {
            $('#show').text(data);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```